Cura plugins folder not showing
I am trying to install a Python plugin into Cura. It said to go to  ..\Ultimaker Cura x.x.x\plugins\PostProcessingPlugin\scripts with the x.x.x being the version.
I typed that after cd into the terminal but it said -bash: cd: ..Ultimaker: No such file or directory. I tried searching for it in Finder, but still nothing. I went into Cura and clicked the Show Configurations Folder, which had the plugins folder in it. I put the plugin into the folder and restarted Cura, but there was still nothing in the plugins section.
Also, I don't know the version of Cura I have. Finder says it's 5.8.1, but the configurations folder said it was 5.8. I tried to go to applications and \Ultimaker\ Cura\ x.x.x\ but I still couldn't find the directory. I am using a Mac.

You say "It said..." - what said? Please [edit] and include the full console output if possible. Also, please use code formatting to make it easier to read.

You are using macOS, I presume, as you mention the Finder. If so, then you need to use forward slashes (/) as path separators.
I'm not sure why the initial message (whatever its source) used backslashes in the path, as that is only Windows and DOS, and rather confuses matters. Maybe it is an unfixed relic from the porting process from Windows to Mac?
If you use cd, you will have to escape the spaces using the backslash character (i.e. use \  not  ) in the file/folder name, so
cd ../Ultimaker\ Cura\ x.x.x/plugins/PostProcessingPlugin/scripts


The reason why you get the error
-bash: cd: ..Ultimaker: No such file or directory.

if you use
cd ../Ultimaker Cura x.x.x/plugins/PostProcessingPlugin/scripts

is because the space after Ultimaker was not escaped, and the shell assumes that Ultimaker is an argument to cd - when, obviously, it is not - and there is no such folder called just Ultimaker (it is Ultimaker Cura x.x.x).

Note that, due to the .., you will also need to already be in a sibling directory (of Ultimaker\ Cura\ x.x.x/), within the (parent) directory, of which Ultimaker\ Cura\ x.x.x/ is a subdirectory. Otherwise you will need to substitute the full path for the .. at the beginning. For example
cd /Applications/Ultimaker\ Cura\ x.x.x/plugins/PostProcessingPlugin/scripts

or, if already in the /Applications directory, then
cd Ultimaker\ Cura\ x.x.x/plugins/PostProcessingPlugin/scripts

It should go without saying that you will also need to substitute the relevant version number for the x.x.x, as that will be just an example given in the initial message.

It still can't find the directory.

Yes, because cd /Ultimaker\ Cura\ x.x.x looks for Ultimaker Cura x.x.x in the root (/) directory, which is, most probably, where it isn't... Also, the directory probably has numbers instead of x in the name. Trying using Spotlight?

You need to use forward slashes, I've amended answer. Not sure why error uses backslashes. I must admit that threw me for quite a while - and made my original answer confusing at best.

By the "it" in the above (your last) comment, I assume you mean the shell running in the terminal. What is this "it" that you refer to, at the start of your question, that said "to go ..\Utlimaker etc.,.."? A post in a thread on the internet, the user guide, or some output of a program? If the latter, then which program? Also, just for the sake of clarity, what OS are you using? Windows or Mac?

I used forward slashes but the shell said the Ultimaker directory doesn't exist.

I found out I put the plugin into the plugins folder instead of the scripts folder. Now, I can find the plugin in Cura.
